# Can I have a hash in my config/settings.yml in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Folks,

In rails in my **config/settings.yml** can I have a hash. For example:

```
specimen_options:
  kinds: [ {:ocl => "latest"}, {:omb => "legacy"}]
```

Comment: You can.. I think you need to use like this: `kinds: <%= [ {:ocl => "latest"}, {:omb => "legacy"}] %>` or you can make it `json` string `kinds: <%= ([ {:ocl => "latest"}, {:omb => "legacy"}]).to_json %>` and use `JSON.parse` to get it back.

Comment: Yaml is actually already a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to have a hash here? You could always nest this properties under kinds and get the same result once you read the YML.

```
specimen_options:
  kinds:
    ocl: latest
    omb: legacy
```

Comment: This is definitely the more canonical way to go in ruby.